# Javascript `onclick` doesn't work in separate JS file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I have to delete some answer so I used onclick event. This event only worked in same html page within the script tag, but it doesn't working on separate js file.

### editquestion.php

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="delete" onClick="deleteAnswer('<?php  if($option->answerId != ''){ echo "{$option->answerId}"; } ?>','old');"><i class="icon md-recycle"></i></a>
```

### user.js

```
function deleteAnswer(uid,value){
  //alert(uid);
  if(value=='old'){
    $("#answer_form_group_"+uid).empty().hide();
    $("#answer_form_group_"+uid).append("<input type='hidden' name='deleteAnswer[]' value='"+uid+"'>");
    } else {
    $("#answer_form_group_"+uid).remove();
  }
}

function addans(){
$('.addans').unbind("click");
$('.addans').on("click",function(e){
    if ((($('#ansform').find(".form-group").length > 4)&&($("#sel1").val() == "multiplechoice"))||
        (($('#ansform').find(".form-group").length > 1)&&($("#sel1").val() == "trueorfalse"))||
        (($('#ansform').find(".form-group").length > 4)&&($("#sel1").val() == "multipleselect"))){
            noty({ text: 'your exceeded the maximium limit',type: 'error',modal:true,timeout:1000});
    } else {
        if(($('#ansform').find(".form-group").length > 0) &&($("#sel1").val() == "")){
            noty({ text: 'select Type of Question ',type: 'warning',modal:true,timeout:1000});
            } else {
            var uid = generateUid();
            var input_type = ($("#sel1").val() == "multiselect")?"checkbox":"radio";
            $('#ansform').append(     
            '<div class="form-group" id="answer_form_group_'+uid+'">'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
            '<input type="text" id= "ans_'+uid+'" class="ans form-control input-lg ans inline" placeholder="Write answers here" name="ans[]">'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="crt[]" value="0" />'+
            '<input type="'+input_type+'" id= "ctr_'+uid+'" class="correct" name="crt[]" value="1">'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="delete" onClick="deleteAnswer(\''+uid+'\',\'new\')"><i class="icon md-recycle"></i></a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'
            ); 
        }   
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
}

function deleteAnswerOption(){
$("#ansform").off('click','.answer-delete');
$('#ansform').on('click', '.answer-delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('class'));
    // $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
}
```

All other functions are working properly but only this one shows error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteAnswer is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`.

Comment: have you included js file in html? and if yes where ?

Comment: This looks like only a partial part of your HTML. Where is the `#answer_form_group_*` element? I also suggest that you try removing any PHP code and make an example of this code in a place like codepen or jsfiddle for people to test.

Comment: check the position of `user.js` is after with  `jquery` library

Comment: What if PHP doesn't echo anything? Are you 100% sure that `$option->answerId` would not be equal to `''` so that it `echo`es it? Because the `deleteAnswer(uid, value)` takes two parameters, so if PHP doesn't return anything then what?

Comment: Also make sure the `scope`  of the function is accessible from the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try with document.ready()

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Paste your functions inside this
```

});

or

```
$(function() {
    //Paste your functions inside this;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you put it into the head section of your html as follows

`<head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
          <!--other script and also external css included over here-->
    </head>`

just replace src="path/to/script.js" with the name of your js file. if its in the the same folder, you won't need to put anything but this

```
"<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>"
```

again, script.js needs to be replaced with the name of your js file

Answer (score 0):

`deleteAnswer(uid, value)` requires two parameters `uid` and `value`.

In your code, you are passing the first parameter via PHP snippet which contains an `if` clause to `echo` some value. What if that PHP snippet doesn't echo anything, what would happen? Exactly! Code will break.

Recommendation: Please insert `else` clause in your PHP snippet which should `echo empty string literal`.

You are welcome :)

Comment: But answer id is geneating. And working in the same page inside script tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.addans',function(){
       alert('Hello Clieck me')
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ta0ubp8j/3/

Comment: Some time JavaScript Not find any html tag. added body then work on properly

Answer (score -1):

To check actual error follow these steps:

1. GO to the browser console of editquestion.php page(press f12 key).
   2.write deleteAnswer("xyz",""); then press enter 
   3.if it will give same "deleteAnswer is not defined error" then there will be two case four this error otherwise it will work.

   - your deleteAnswer function not define globally so you need to define it globally.
   - define all javascript code within 
     $(document).ready(function(){*** your javascript code  *******})
2. if this will not work then check in browser console , anchor tag will not with proper deleteAnser function may be your php script breaks function syntax.